# Why does a ConstraintLayout with layout_constraintDimensionRatio resize when data loads?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a header data template to be populated with some text and a picture. I'd like its size to obey the 16:9 aspect ratio.

This ConstraintLayout stays constrained to the height of the placeholder image, `@dimen/profile_icon_size` (72dp), while the async call is in progress. The placeholder drawable is drawn at the correct size but appears to jump downward when the layout redraws. Amazingly, when the data is drawn after binding, not only does the whole ConstraintLayout resize, but the final displayed size of the ConstraintLayout is 5-10dp shorter or taller every time.

Am I missing some constraints? What else could be missing?

Here's my XML:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/horizontalCenterGuide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_icon_size"
            app:imageUrl="@{person.imageUrl}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_component_button_text_left_and_right_padding"
            app:firstName="@{person.firstName}"
            app:lastName="@{person.lastName}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/horizontalCenterGuide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profileIcon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_component_button_text_left_and_right_padding"
            android:text="@{person.emailAddress}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profileIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalCenterGuide" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add this line to image view app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
set width and height to "0dp"